# GTK on Pi with Geany

Tags: user-interface, gtk, pi, geany

I have been trying all day to get this working and everything that I find on the internet to try fails.

Using Geany on the Raspbery Pi I want to make a GUI for C.

In my build commands I have this

```
gcc `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` -Wall -o "%e" "%f" `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0`
```

And here is my code.  I commented out the parts for wiringpi for now.

```
//#include <wiringPi.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    gtk_init (&argc, &argv);
    //wiringPiSetup () ;
    //pinMode (0, OUTPUT) ;
    while (1){
        //digitalWrite (0, HIGH) ; 
        //delayMicroseconds(30);
        //digitalWrite (0,  LOW) ; 
        //delayMicroseconds(30);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I get the following errors

Package gtk+-3.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `gtk+-3.0.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'gtk+-3.0' found
Package gtk+-3.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing`gtk+-3.0.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'gtk+-3.0' found
untitled.c:2:21: fatal error: gtk/gtk.h: No such file or directory

It looks like I might be missing a gtk+-3.0.pc file.  If that is the case where might I look for it, and if I don't have it then where do I get it?

Comment: Have you installed the libgtk-3.0-dev package?

Comment: I tried that but was getting errors such as file not found or server not found.  I tried to do the update option but that didn't seem to help.  After reading you post I tried it again and it worked!  While the package install was running I searched the internet some more and found this post that seems to explain/solve my problem.  [link](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=201616)